# How can we imnplement curl animation in viewPager as turning of a images

Tags: animation, curl, android-viewpager

I am working on a photo album android app, in which the next image should come as the curl effect in album. For this i am using ViewPager to show image, but don't know how to implement curl animation. Please help....